# ADF Copy data from Table to Azure Blob with headers

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am using ADF to copy data from Snowflake table (Source) to Azure Blob CSV file (Sink).

The Sink dataset has “First row as header” checked.

It works well if the source table contains data.

However, if the source table is empty, the generated file is empty without a header.

Please see the screenshots for the settings.

I wonder how to make the generated file with header regardless of whether the source table is empty or not.

Thank you.

[image: source]
[image: sink]
[image: blob]

Comment: Maybe you can build a query to fashion up a union on the column headers (which would therefore be represented as a record instead of headers) with the resulting data.  You'd need to do some smarts for that but I suspect it would be pretty straight forward.  That way, you'd always get the header records regardless of whether there's data or not.

Comment: I'm aware there are various methods like using a Union header, but I'm seeking a simpler approach. I'm curious if such an alternative exists.

Comment: Yeah there is … always make sure there’s a record. Simple!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below workaround, to copy the header into the target file.

- First Check the table count using lookup activity. Then use if activity to check whether the count is `0` or not.
- Add two copy activities one in True activities of if and another is in false activities.
- You need to use different target datasets with same target file path for the two copy activities.
- One copy activity is to copy the headers and if the count is not `0`, other one is for regular copy to target file.

Use the below query in the lookup to get the count of the table.

```
select count(*) as count from emp
```

[image]

Then give the below expression in the if activity.

```
@equals(activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].COUNT,0)
```

Inside **True activities** of if, use the below query for the source of the copy activity.

```
select listagg(column_name,',') from information_schema.columns
where table_schema ilike 'public' and table_name ilike 'emp'
```

[image]

If the **column delimiter in your target file** is `|`, you need to use `|` instead of `,` like this `listagg(column_name,'|')` in the above query.

This will give the **Delimiter(,) seperated column names** as one row with a column name `LISTAGG(COLUMN_NAME,',')` like below.

```
LISTAGG(COLUMN_NAME,',')
Id,name
```

But here, we only want the row which has required headers not the column name.

So, in the **sink dataset of this copy activity**, uncheck the `First row as header` and give the below configurations. This is the reason to use different datasets for both copy activities.

[image]

**You can change the Column delimiter as per your requirement, but you need to change that in the query as well**.

In the **False activities of if**, Give your regular copy activity with another  target dataset.

Execute the pipeline and your headers will be copied like below in the Blob.

[image]